# Special characters deleted when post JSON

Tags: json, curl

I need to post the following JSON, but all special characters are deleted

```
$curl2 = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl2, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/api',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'X-apikey: 123456',
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl2);

curl_close($curl2);
$a = json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $response), true);
```

I've changed the header like this but the problem still persists :

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-apikey: 123456',
),
```

Comment: try `'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-16',`

Comment: also I suggest you check with the API service, if they support UTF-8 or UTF-16, UNICODE, or ISO character sets.

Comment: I've tried `'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-16',` but not works